# How can I change a CSS values on a DIV by clicking on an A tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When any `<a>` tag is clicked with the `id="cnt"` I want to set the border color of `div#fancybox-content` to `#000`. My attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('a#cnt').click(function(){
        $("#fancybox-content").css("border-color","#000");
    }); 
});
```

This code does not work.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you meant "id of 'cnt'"? you said "When any a tag is clicked"... is there more than one?

Make sure you set the other border parameters as well

If there is more than one, use a class:

```
$().ready( function() {
  $("a.cnt").click(function() {
    $("#fancybox-content").css({"border-width":"1px", "border-style":"solid", "border-color":"#000"});
  });
})
```

see - http://jsbin.com/avuxe3/3

If there really is one:

```
$().ready( function() {
  $("#cnt").click(function() {
    $("#fancybox-content").css({"border-width":"1px", "border-style":"solid", "border-color":"#000"});
  });
})

enter code here
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It's just one tag. I am working in wordpress and using gravity forms + fancybox to open a form in a modal window. I only need for the modal forms to have different fancybox styles than modal pictures. It worked ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in which selector you use. If you have a single HTML element that has an ID, use the `#` selector. If there is more than one element, you should use a class rather than ID and use the `.` selector. Below are examples:

If you have a single `A` tag, with an `id="cnt"` then you would use:

```
$('a#cnt').click(function() {
    $('#fancybox-content').css({"border":"solid 1px #000"});
});
```

If you have more than one anchor with the `cnt` notation, set it as `class="cnt"` and use:

```
$('a.cnt').click(function() {
    $('#fancybox-content').css({"border":"solid 1px #000"});
});
```

---

Better yet, keep your styles in a stylesheet like this

```
.borderOn { border: solid 1px #000; }
```

And then toggle this class on (and off if you like) with your links' click events:

```
$('a.cnt').click(function() {
    $('#fancybox-content').addClass('borderOn');
});
```